# Multiple flexbox row with multiple scrollview in react native

Tags: react-native, flexbox

I am trying to build a view with two rows in an iPhone using react native. I want to have two rows with equal height with scroll view. I am not able to find much documentation on this. I am the below code but it just renders on top of each other.

```
      <View style={Styles.splitView}>
        <View style={Styles.splitViewLeft}>
          <ScrollView>
              <Text>Test1</Text>}
          </ScrollView>
        </View>
        <View style={Styles.splitViewRight}>
          <ScrollView>
            {
              <Text>Test2</Text>
            }
          </ScrollView>
        </View>
      </View>

      splitView: {
        flexDirection: 'row'
      },

      splitViewLeft: {
        flex: 3
      },

      splitViewRight: {
        flex: 2
      },
```

Answer (score 1):

This does the work:

```js
<View style={{flex: 1}}>
  <ScrollView style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'red'}}>
    <Text>Test1</Text>
  </ScrollView>
  <ScrollView style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'yellow'}}>
    <Text>Test2</Text>
  </ScrollView>
</View>
```

Apply style `flex: 1` on both `<ScrollView />` to make them equal height.

If you wrap it inside parent `<View />`, you have to apply `flex: 1` to `<ScrollView />` too.